# Presentation matrix column operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I refer to Jim Howie's notes from http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~jim/F13YR1/ .
On page 72, it is claimed that subtracting a multiple of one column from another does not change the isomorphism type. Is there any way to see this?